# How do I break out of /home/reveller/ in terminal?

Tags: command-line

Ubuntu newbie here. I succesfully installed Ubuntu on a VM on Windows. I am now trying to run a `localhost` website using `nginx`.

I have read tutorials online on how to create your website in `/var/www` and that you will have to create also these folders if they dont exist.

So at the terminal I did this because the `/var/www`-folder did indeed not exist on my system:

```
root@Ubuntu-VM:/home/reveller# mkdir /var/www
```

Later I realized that `/var/www` is actually an existing directory. I have been creating `/home/user/reveller/var/www` while `/var/www/` was  already there.

I am now trying to access `/var/www/` via terminal, but in my terminal prompt I cannot seem to go to a lower level in the filestructure than `/home/reveller`.

Question:

**Question 1:** How can I launch a terminal with prompt `root@Ubuntu-VM:/var/www#` instead of `root@Ubuntu-VM:/home/reveller#`?

I hope I am making myself clear. I read about `sudo` but the following makes no difference:

```
root@Ubuntu-VM:/home/reveller# sudo su
root@Ubuntu-VM:/home/reveller#
```

How do I traverse up the tree until I am in `/var/`?

**Question 2** When I try to create new folders in `/var/` via the GUI filebrowser, I am unable to -- the *New Folder*, *New Document* and *Paste* commands are greyed out and cannot be clicked. How can I open an elevated GUI filebrowser that allows me to create, copy and paste folders troughout the filestructure?

Answer (score 1):

**Changing your home directory**

```
sudo usermod  -d /var/www  your_username
```

The reason that `sudo su` is not doing anything for you is because you are already the root user.

**Traversing a directory**

To traverse up a file tree, you have to use the `cd` command. So in your case, you would have to do `cd /var/`

Comment: Thanks! In the terminal, i am now indeed able to browse to `/var/` but if I am trying to copy the `/www` directory from my `home` folder to `/var` using `cp -a /home/reveller/var/www/ /var/www/` (folder `/var/www/` does not yet exist) I get an error: `cp: cannot create directory ‘/var/www/’: Permission denied`. User `reveller` is indeed root (by using `whoami`), so why is this not working and what can I do about it?

Comment: You have to be sudo by typing in `sudo -i` or `sudo su` either one will work fine.